# Keyword research: 'docx converter' in Google

Tags: seo, google, search-engines, keywords, research

Why did not **docxconverter.com** show up when I type **docx converter** in **google**? The closest match is **www.docx-converter.com**.

My question 1: What are the reasons for **www.docxconverter.com** not showing up?

My question 2: Which among the domain **www.docxconverter.com** and **www.docx-converter.com** is friendly with keyword phrase docx converter, and why?

Answer (score 1):

1) docxconverter.com is not indexed by Google
2) content is more important than the domain name for more information you can check [How important is the domain name for SEO](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3548/how-important-is-the-domain-name-for-seo)

Comment: Could you imagine if google didn't ignore parked and squatted sites?  Oh the SEO horror!

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no real website at *docxconverter.com*, it's just a domain-squatting page and has zero value. That same content is on literally thousands, maybe millions of pages. *docx-converter.com* on the other hand is a real site with content.
2. Both are equal as far as I know (though there is a tiny chance non-hyphen will rank better). However, for *users* it's best to avoid hyphens in domain names, because they are easier to remember and dictate to others.