# Generic or brandable name for blog

Tags: domains, blog, branding

This [question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3548/how-important-is-the-domain-name-for-seo) looked like a duplicate, but it's actually talking about domains in general which may include company domains. My question is about blog domains. And all the answers in that question date back in 2010. Many things have now changed on how Google ranks sites today.

I am creating a blog that will host Python tutorials for beginners and I will add new content regularly.

I am quite confused though on whether I should go with a branded name such as pyclass.com or a generic name such as pythonhow.com

Or to not confine the question to my specific case, I will give more examples.

A blog about learning music:
mysica.com or musicacademy.com?

A blog about dating advice: 
pickuper.com or getdatesquickly.com?

I am stuck now, and can't wrap my mind to whether branded domains such as pyclass, mysica and pickuper are better than the generic ones.

Comment: This question requires primarily opinion-based answers over a name which will cause it to be closed soon. If you can redo the question so it can generate fact-based answers instead of opinions, then the question may stay open.

Comment: @Mike You are mostly right except for one factor - the semantic value of the domain name. Both domain names have little value except that one would perform better in search because of the semantic value of the domain name which is a significant factor these days.

Comment: I edited the question by making it more generic so that it becomes useful for others as well.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what is branded about pyclass.com. A brand is a "Top of Mind" name that people would search for specifically at minimum. According to domain tools, this domain name was registered this year, but there are also hints that the domain name existed before with a rough and unstable history. Pythonhow.com has a cleaner history. This is important for trust.

It really is a choice at this point between the two. Both domains are of the same relative value with one significant exception - semantics. The domain name pyclass.com would have almost no semantic value whereas pythonhow.com would have more. Keep in mind that semantic value is based upon terms being found in an ontology or a well established brand which you do not have at this point. So for pyclass.com, *class* is the only term of value whereas for pythonhow.com you would have *python* and *how*. The next thing to do is a simple search for *py class* and *python how* to see which one returns results similar to your topic. I will save you the effort and tell you it is pythonhow.com. Though direct term matches against domain names are lower on the list and mostly happens last if at all, the *semantic value* of the domain name is a significant factor in returning results - one of the top factors in fact.

[Update]

-*Maybe I was trying to say "brandable", not branded.*

There is no such thing as brandable. I have been building businesses my entire adult life including back in high-school. There is one truth about brands. You do not make them- you enable them- people make brands and you do not have control over the process.

There is no such thing as a formula that makes one thing brandable. Xerox as a brand for example, would not have happened without a killer product in every office. Pepsi as a brand followed it's main and well known ingredient pepsin which was already in every household and had been for a century. Coca-Cola had a much harder time. Coca was taken from the coca plant from South America and the kola nut from Africa which no one was familiar with. Rebranding as Coke was necessary. Kleenex was the first on the market.

What a brand has to be first and foremost is memorable, and "Top of Mind" which is a marketing concept meaning the first to come to mind when solving a problem. You may have Scotties facial tissue in your house, but you call them Kleenex.

*I go back to value.*

Funny names and spelling make branding harder. Xerox would not have happened except for the a killer product. The brand name means nothing to us. Same with Coca-Cola. It meant nothing. Pepsi, on the other hand was based on pepsin which was in every medicine cabinet. It meant something automatically.

A brand is something that is memorable and top of mind. Top of mind is something memorable. Getting the pattern yet??

I also go back to the semantic value of a domain name. Any domain name that contains terms/words that exist in an ontology which is a semantics database one of which is a dictionary work best. Remember my example of doing a search for the terms within the domain name? It is imperative that the terms within the domain name *match* search intent. This means that the search query results should match what the site is about. As well, known terms are memorable. Trust me. I have had many domain names of various names over the years. I was one of the first web hosts and registered ISPs in the world and a principle presenter at ISPOne for exactly that reason. I have handled thousands of domain names over the years. I personally had registered over 300 at one point. The ones that worked best are the ones people can already tie to intent and are easily remembered. The domain names that did not fall within this category failed.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Didn't think of the domain history. I did register pyclass one year ago. Maybe I was trying to say "brandable", not branded. I edited the question hoping it is more clear what I am asking.

Comment: Learned a lot from your answer - thanks again. And I was able to deduct that pythonhow.com is the way to go. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: The terms in your domain http://www.closetnoc.org/ though don't match the search intent. Am I wrong?

Comment: @A.S Regarding my remaining domain names - you are exactly right. They are all failed domain names. ;-) ClosetNOC was supposed to be phone *closet* and network operations center (*NOC*). I registered the domain name before I understood the concept for a business I was building. I only use it because I have had it for so long. I am retired and just farting around - so what would be the point to change it now?? It is clear you have the concept! ClosetNOC means nothing. In fact, most of the advertising on my site is for closet systems. Great! Just what I wanted. Nice catch!!

Comment: Makes sense. Just saw an ad about hotel booking. Probably coming from the word closet (room).
I was also thinking of just using my personal name as domain (i.e.namesurname.com), but I have no idea how that would go.

Comment: @A.S I suggest using personal names for clean blogs and professional profiles. There is nothing wrong with then putting python coding lessons on a personal domain, however, it would possibly detract from any professional profile depending. If you can make sure you can demonstrate you are an python expert and you want to code professionally, fine. Otherwise, it could be a detraction. I found that domain names that represent a person should be clean, simple, and professional. If, for example, you want to have a bombastic political blog, do not put it under your name unless you can take the fire.

Answer (score 1):

3 things you need to consider

1. You need to think of the long-term goal. So ask yourself, Do you stick with python for a long time? If you say "yes" then go with pyclass.com
2. During my recent testing, a domain name which actually tells what the domain is about, is more likely people to remember and follow. Kind of similar effect to taglines for a company.
3. The 3rd thing is, In the future you may have an idea of covering another language, but you may not cover since the domain is on the python. So based on the long term plan decide it.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Suresh! 
1. Yes
2. Most memorable is certainly pythonhow.com
3. That's a good point too.